# Create a plot showing the duration of time a player was in the team

Tags: python, pandas

this is an example data frame, i will be working with much larger data frames.
I need to create a plot to show the duration of time a player stayed at the club - the plot is not exclusive to each team in this plot. But my second plot will be showing the correlation between the team and the duration of staying. but I keep getting several errors and i am unsure on how to use 'matplot.lib' assuming that's what i should be using, to begin with.

Thank you in advance. Sorry if this has been answered before.

| Name | Age | Team | Joined_on | Lost_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benjamin | 18 | A FC | 2019-01-13 | NaN |
| Natty | 17 | A FC | 2016-05-06 | 2022-01-12 |
| Smith | 19 | C FC | 2016-01-13 | NaN |
| Will | 15 | A FC | 2020-03-09 | NaN |
| Harry | 20 | B FC | 2020-09-09 | 2021-01-01 |

Comment: if you get errors then show them in question (not in comments) as text (not image). We can't see your code, we can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind. And don't expect that we will write all code for this problem. You have to show all details in question.

Comment: first you may have to create new column `lost_on` with current date instead of `NaN`. And  next convert all strings with dates to `datetime` objects - `pd.to_datetime()`. And later you may substract `df["duration"] = df["lost_on"] - df["joined_on"]`. And finally you can plot - `df["duration"].plot()`

Answer (score 0):

As furas mentioned, this should be pretty direct once you convert the missing dates to today's dates and then apply a difference to extract the duration column.

**Here's the complete code for the dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creating dataframe
data = {'Name':['Benjamin','Natty','Smith','Will','Harry'],
       'Age':[18,17,19,15,20],
       'Team':['A FC','A FC','C FC','A FC','B FC'],
       'Joined_on': ['2019-01-13','2016-05-06','2016-01-13','2020-03-09','2020-09-09'],
       'Lost_on': [np.nan,'2022-01-12',np.nan,np.nan,'2021-01-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#fill nan with todays date
df['Lost_on'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), inplace= True)

#convert to datetime formats
df['Joined_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joined_on'])
df['Lost_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Lost_on'])

#duration column
df['Duration'] = (df['Lost_on'] - df['Joined_on'])#time delta

df
```

**Outputs:**

[image: Output table]

Because the duration columns in this table are in `timedelta` format, you may convert them to integers and plot them. I prefer plotly, however, if matplotlib is required in this situation, you may do it as follows:

```
#name and duration
plt.bar(df['Name'], df['Duration'].dt.days, edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.7)
```

[image: Name and Duration]

```
#teams and duration
plt.bar(df.Team, df.Duration.dt.days)
```

I'm not sure what kind of correlation you're looking for, you may use a similar framework and plot using the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/search.html?q=correlation) manual for your relevant chart.

[image: correlation for teams]